# How to close window using [x] in corner without it freezing?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to click the [x] in the corner of the window and for it to shut the whole application. Instead it is freezing up and not responding. Thanks for any help.

```
import sys
#import and init pygame
import pygame
pygame.init() 

#create the screen
window = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480)) 

#draw a line - see http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html for more 
pygame.draw.line(window, (255, 255, 255), (0, 0), (30, 50))

#draw it to the screen
pygame.display.flip() 

#input handling (somewhat boilerplate code):
while True: 
for event in pygame.event.get(): 
   if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
      sys.exit(0) 
  else: 
      print event
```

I'm used to java and so was wondering if there was a dispose and close type action for the frame.

Comment: Or, if `while True:` is `while not done:` and on quit you set `done = True` it will quit fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a `pygame.quit()` before the `sys.exit(0)` to shut down the pygame window, like so:

```
import sys

import pygame
pygame.init() 

window = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480)) 
pygame.draw.line(window, (255, 255, 255), (0, 0), (30, 50))
pygame.display.flip() 

while True: 
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit(0) 
        else: 
            print event
```